# Writing a buffer overflow exploit

Tags: security, buffer-overflow

I understand there are quite a few tutorials on how to write a buffer overflow, but still can't write my own.

The following is the C code I want to hack:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int x = 8;

void prompt(){
    char buf[100];

    gets(buf);
    printf("You entered: %s\n", buf);

}

int main(){
    prompt();

    return 0;
}

void target(){
    printf("Haha! I made it!\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

My goal is to execute the target () function via a buffer overflow exploit.
Through trial and error, I've discovered the minimum number of characters required to obtain a segmentation fault is 108. (Therefore 107 characters does NOT cause seg fault)
I've disassembled the binary, and found the target executable to be at address 0x08048e7f

I've flipped the byte order to compensate for endian-ness. --> 0x7f8e0408
I then converted that hexadecimal to a binary, then to ASCII, obtaining: & # 3 8 1 ;   (ignore spaces, stackoverflow doesn't properly show it originally)
Afterwards, I inserted the first 107 characters, and then Ž

Thus, my attack string is: iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiŽ
This still gives me a segmentation fault.
I've compiled like so:

```
gcc ./vuln_program.c -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -static -o vuln_program
```

and have disabled protections beforehand like so:

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0
```

I am using a 32 bit Ubuntu virtual machine.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

EDIT:
I just realized that my output on this site is being read as weird characters.
If you see a weird Z, it really is 1) & 2) # 3) 3  4)8  5) 1 6) ;    in that exact order

Comment: you are overflowing, but your overflow is basically just some text. that's only useful for filling up the buffer you want to overflow. everything past that point needs to be code/data that'll aid in the overflow. e.g. if you're overflowing a stack, the overflow should replace the "return to this place" address that was pushed by the normal code, with an address of your choosing. that address would be wherever your `target` function is.

Comment: Why binary then to ASCII? Shouldn't `7f` be the `DEL` character in ASCII? Write your exploit in something like Python or Ruby and use [Evans Debugger](http://freecode.com/projects/edebugger) to debug your exploit to see where execution is ending up in memory.